# unable to create add cart button in magento in product listing page for configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9

I have many products in my store (Magento). But in the list page configurable products are not adding to Cart. Googled lot and dig the code but no luck. Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configurable product is not allowed for add to cart without selecting configurable options. You have to go to product detail page and select
option and add to card.

If you want to add configurable product from list page, then you have to
develop or integrate 'quick view' feature. Here, you will get
configurable options on popup and select and add to cart.

Comment: hello we want our requirment